# Joda Time get Duration between two Instants

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two `Instant` objects and would like to get a `Duration` indicating how much time is between them, however `Instant.minus` only accepts either a `ReadableDuration` or a `long` for the amount of time to change by, and doesn't seem to have any method for subtracting two instants to get the difference between them.

Other answers that I found seem to suggest converting both instants to milliseconds and doing the math myself, but I would prefer something that retains type safety and doesn't require re-implementing end - start logic.

How can I get a `Duration` from two `Instant`s?

Answer (score 6):

`Duration` has a constructor which takes two `ReadableInstant` objects for the start and end of the `Duration`.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#Duration(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)